# The best technique to manage "session" object

Tags: android, android-service

I know that this is possibly not a proper question for SO but I need an advice for my app.

I have a library which manages some network requests (sync and async). Before any request is possible user have to log in and in this moment session object is created. After that I have to use this object for all requests.
My question is how do I have to manage this object.

I have 2 approaches:

1. Store it as static var inside `Application` subclass. The pros are that it's easy to use. The cons are that I actually don't like this approach.
2. After user logs in I can start a `Service` subclass using `startService` command and store session object in it. The pros are that I feel this way more 'Androidish'. The cons are that I'm afraid of `Service` being destroyes while user works with an app. If it is destroyes when application is paused it's OK if it's not done very often. Offcorse I can use `bindService` method in every `Activity` after user logs in and even create `Notification` to keep it alive during long tasks but I'm not sure that this is right decision.

I actually never used complex services before (only simple ones for single tasks) so I need an advice to do it right and I can't find any proper example (each one is too simple). Notice that for some session related tasks I have to spawn threads and I also need to somehow check if some tasks are in progress inside my `Activity` classes (just to display progress indication inside of them).

Comment: Could you describe what is this session object of your? is it a authentication token returned by the server or it stores the user credentials to be reused in each of the other server calls?

Comment: It's neither both. It's Java's Session object (let's call it so) and it's implementation is hidden from me.

Comment: Since your are not using an oAuth flow and since you can not recreate your session wihtout making the call to your service i guess @sockeqwe second option is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something really "Androidish" let the system handle your Account using the [AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html)

Here is a nice tutorial : https://udinic.wordpress.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

1. AccountManager: but that is a little bit messy if you plan to work with oAuth and refresh tokens.
2. SharedPreferences: Simply store the User information in shared preferences (please not store the password) and before starting a network request check if the user is logged in by querying shared preferences (query session object from here).

Comment: But without password I can't silently log in again. AccountManager... well I'll take a look at it but I'm not sure that it's possible to use it in my case since I have to use already written library which handle authentication.

Comment: nowadays you work with oAuth access tokens where no username or password is required anymore once you arr signed in. Thats also what AccountManager assumes. If you really have to store the password, i would recomment to store it encrypted